# Retrieiving clsid for installed components

Tags: object, com

I'm trying to get a list of clsid's for COM objects so that when I try to use an object, I know what the clsid is for the  tag.

Thanks

Tom Magaro

Answer (score 0):

Try the program "OLE-COM Object Viewer" that ships with the Windows SDK (you'll find it from the start menu). That shows you all the com objects that are registered on the system. It's a little limited though as you don't seem to be able to search within it. You can also use Regedit to do any searching as most COM objects have entries in the registry.